# mongosh shell how to insert a new id with objectid

Tags: mongodb, shell

I am using mongosh (mongo shell) and inserting a new collection. in the top level collection if i don't put the id. it does so automatically.

how ever, in array inside the collection i also have ID. however in mongo SHELL i don't know how to insert objectId rather than a string id

how do i insert Object id in mongo shell?

```
db.polls.insert({
 // here mongo will auto generate _id with objectid
  "pollListOfOptions": [
    {
      "sub_array": [
        {
          "name": "test",
        }
      ],
      "_id": "6421569b123123adabc696399" // how do i make sure this one is also object id via mongo shell? 
    },
    ....

})
```

Comment: Use `"_id": ObjectId("6421569b123123adabc696399")`

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#behavior) is how to do in mongosh:

```
newObjectId = ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea")
```